# Link to another page when click on an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe showing a page. I would like the user to be redirected on another page when I click anywhere on the iframe (and not to navigate inside the iframe).

I though about:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <iframe src="http://www.kernel.org"></iframe>
</a>
```

but it is obviously not working.

Comment: does the user need to interact with the iframe? (i am thinking about using an overlay), or can u access the `contentDocument` of the iframe?

Comment: No need to interact.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

Html

```
<div class="location">
   <iframe src="http://www.kernel.org"></iframe>
</div>
```

Js

```
$('.location').click(function(){
    window.location="http://www.google.com";
 });
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without jquery?

Comment: You want to be redirected from the page that iframe is on or only redirect from page inside iframe?

Comment: from the page that iframe is on.